# How to check if an object is an instance of a template class in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I check if a variable is a template class without knowing the template argument, so in the example below, how do I determine (prove) that A<int> is an A.

```cpp
template <class T>
class A {/*----*/};

int main() {
    auto a1 = A<int>();
    bool is_a1_an_A = some_method(a1, A);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using a specialized helper class:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class A {};

template<typename T>
struct is_a : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_a<A<T>> : std::true_type {};


int main()
{
    auto a1=A<int>{};

    bool b1=false;

    std::cout << is_a<decltype(a1)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_a<decltype(b1)>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`is_a` gets specialized for a template parameter that's any instance of `A`. The non-specialized version is the false trait, and the specialized version is the true trait, and that's pretty much it. If you are not familiar with the topic of template specialization, this is a fairly involved and deep topic that should have a full explanation in every good C++ textbook, and I refer you there for a full and complete discussion on this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! While this does indeed work in most cases, because of `decltype`, it doesn't really work for polymorphic cases, as opposed to `typeid`. Would you know any method using `typeid`, or is that impossible?

Comment: That is impossible. C++ does not work this way. In C++, the types of all objects must be fully defined at compile-time, not runtime. This is a fundamental aspect of C++.