# How to check if an object is an instance of a template class of multiple template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T, typename U = UDefault>
class A;
```

How to check whether types such as `A<float>` or `A<float, int>` are instances of the above templated class?

I tried modifying [How to check if an object is an instance of a template class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226698/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-template-class-in-c) into:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsA : std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsA<A<T, U>> : std::true_type
{};
```

but it's giving the following error

```
20:18: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
16:8: error: provided for 'template<class T, class U> struct IsA'
 In function 'int main()':
40:34: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
16:8: error: provided for 'template<class T, class U> struct IsA'
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `IsA` class should be expected to take **one** template argument.  The type you are testing.

```
template <typename Type>
struct IsA : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsA< A<T,U> > : std::true_type {};
//          ^^^^^^ The specialization of your one template argument.
```

Or put alternately, since the individual template parameters to A do not matter here:

```
template <typename ...AParams>
struct IsA< A<AParams...> > : std::true_type {};
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The specialization of your one template argument.
```

[See it work in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rPWozeh4Y)