# How to check if an object is an instance of template class of multiple template arguments and that one of said arguments fulfills some condition?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

From [How to check if an object is an instance of a template class of multiple template arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279095/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-template-class-of-multiple-templat/72279177#72279177) I got the following trait to check whether a type is a particular template instantiation of a templated type of several template arguments:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A
{
};

template <typename Type>
struct IsA: std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsA<A<T1, T2>> : std::true_type
{
};
```

How would one additionally add the condition that the second type `T2` fulfills some other condition?
I tried doing

```
template <typename Type>
struct IsA: std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::enable_if_t<SomeCondition<T2>::value>>
struct IsA<A<T1, T2>> : std::true_type
{
};
```

but am getting the error

```
error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A
{
};

template <typename Type, typename=void>
struct IsA: std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsA<A<T1, T2>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T2, int>>>
    : std::true_type
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << IsA<int>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << IsA<A<char, char>>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << IsA<A<char, int>>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In this trivial example the "some condition" is just a `std::is_same_v<T2, int>`, only for the sake of an example.